# How to emit an event when the user clicks on a specific page number?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
export default {
  props: {
    pageNumber: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {

      currentPage: 1,
      perPage: 12,

    },
    computed: {
        rows() {
          return this.productsList.length;
        },
        paginatedItems() {
          return this.productsList.slice(
            this.currentPage * this.perPage,
            (this.currentPage + 1) * this.perPage
          );
        },


        methods: {


          handleClick(event, pageNumber) {
            alert('hi');
          },
        },
```

```html
<div class="listview-plp" v-for="product in paginatedItems" :key="product.key" id="product" :items="productsList" :per-page="perPage" :current-page="currentPage">
  <div>ds</div>

  <b-pagination v-model="currentPage" :total-rows="rows" :per-page="perPage" @change="loadPage" :pageNumber="currentPage" @page-click="handleClick(event, pageNumber)"></b-pagination>
```

I want to emit an event when the user clicks on a specific page number? For that @page-click="handleClick(event, pageNumber)" i have taken an event in the method. But using page number is not pointing to specific page, So i have tool some prop value and then passing it to them,

But not sure how to pass value for each page.

Comment: try `@page-click="handleClick($event, currentPage)"`

Comment: @bassxzero I tried it, But how to specify that particular event is applicable only for one page, And if user click on 2 or 3 page how to add one more event for that particular page.

PageNumber in the props, Do i need to write as pageNumber1, pageNumber2, pageNumber3,..... –

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the parameters in the template,

```
@page-click="handleClick"
```

the method :

```
    methods: {


      handleClick(event ,pageNumber) {
        alert('hi ', pageNumber);
      },
    },
```

Comment: I tried it, But how to specify that particular event is applicable only for one page, And if user click on 2 or 3 page how to add one more event for that particular page

Comment: PageNumber in the props, Do i need to write as pageNumber1, pageNumber2, pageNumber3,.....

Comment: Please any suggestions?